# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: linq, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST to get some aggregations to work, but what I always get is "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key"

I updated the query

Could you please help me.

Code:

```
 var agg = esclient.Search<Artifact>(s => s.Aggregations(ag => ag
            .Filter("refineSearch", fi => fi.Filter(fl => fl.Bool(b => b
                .Should(sh => sh.Terms("multimediaReferenceList.mimeType", input.Filters.Media)
                              && sh.Terms("physicalLocations.level1", input.Filters.Location)
                              && sh.Terms("objectCategory", input.Filters.Type)
                              && sh.Range(r => r.GreaterOrEquals(input.Years[0]).OnField(of => of.MinYear))
                              && sh.Range(ra => ra.LowerOrEquals(input.Years[1]).OnField(od => od.MaxYear)))))
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                        .Terms("type", att => att.Field("objectCategory"))
                        .Terms("media", att => att.Field("multimediaReferenceList.mimeType"))
                        .Terms("location", att => att.Field("physicalLocations.level1"))))));
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)   at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.Aggregations.AggregationConverter.GetNestedAggregations(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.Aggregations.AggregationConverter.GetSingleBucketAggregation(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.Aggregations.AggregationConverter.ReadAggregation(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.Aggregations.AggregationConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IDictionary dictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeUsingSettings[T](Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeInternal[T](Stream stream, JsonConverter converter)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.FieldsSearchDeserializer[T,TResult](IElasticsearchResponse response, Stream stream, ISearchRequest d)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.<>c__DisplayClass1f9`2.<CreateSearchDeserializer>b__1f8(IElasticsearchResponse r, Stream s)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.StreamToTypedResponse[T](ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ITransportRequestState requestState, Byte[] readBytes)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.ReturnTypedResponse[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ElasticsearchServerError& error)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.Request[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Object data)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.Search[T](Object body, Func`2 requestParameters)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Search[T,TResult](Func`2 searchSelector)
   at THF.CMS.Api.SearchManager.GetSearchResults(SearchRequest input) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SearchManager.cs:line 71
```

Comment: The error message and stacktrace is obvious and immediately tells you whats wrong. Within that crazy amount of aggregation chaining, a specific value, which should be used as a key in a dictionary, is null. Review your data and consider refactoring of that huge codecaterpillar. It could facilitate improved debugging and validation of data and aggregation

Comment: Or at least consider formatting the statements to have a visual feedback on individual queries/aggregations

Answer (score 0):

You tried searching something in a `Dictionary` using `null` for the key, i.e.:

```
Dictionary<DataType, AlsoDataType> dict = new Dictionary<DataType, AlsoDataType>();

DataType key = null;

Console.WriteLine(dict[key].ToString()); // <-------- key is null
```

Comment: I use NEST and there is no way for me know where and which value is null. 

I tried splitting up the Linq and I get an exception stating Unable to deserialize Integer.

Comment: Unexpected token when deserializing object: Integer. Path 'aggregations.names.doc_count_error_upper_bound'

Nest Code: 
 var exp = esclient.Search<Artifact>(s => s.Aggregations(
                    ag =>
                        ag.Terms("names",
                            st =>
                                st.Field("objectCategory")
                                    .Size(10)
                                    .Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("type", t => t.Field(f => f.ObjectCategory))))));

This nest code is the sample nest code from the NEST website